# SharePoint online error message when applying a modern site template

Tags: site, template

I saved a SharePoint online modern site as a template and tried to install it to a different site collection within the same tenant. Uploading and activating the .wsp solution worked but when I went to select it as a custom template I received the following error message:

Features not activated

I then used PowerShell to activate the hidden features as described here:

https://praveensharepointknowledgebase.wordpress.com/2018/02/28/activate-hidden-site-features-using-powershell/

I'm now getting the following error message:

Sorry, something went wrong The field specified with name _TopicHeader and ID {d60d65ff-ff42-4044-a684-ac3f7a5e598c} is not accessible or does not exist.

TopicHeader does not exist

I have been searching the forums for similar messages but so far no luck.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Using the save site as template feature with modern sites is not supported. Unfortunately, there are no simple ways of doing this, but perhaps check out the PNP project for provisioning, or the new "site design" feature. Unfortunately, both require developer skill sets.